# Почему форма не меняет размер до минимума если Visibility = "Collapsed"? C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть 2 формы одна основная другая побочная, вызывается из основной, в побочной форме есть элементы которые изначально имеют видимость "Collapsed", когда форма появляется она почему то имеет не минимальный размер, а размер как будто бы элементы видны и занимают место, хотя на данный момент они Collapsed. **SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"** установлено в основном окне. Так же когда я переключаю комбо бокс элементы исчезают и появляются, но форма не реагирует, даже если пользователь её не трогал.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Насколько мне известно, и не должна. Форма может подстраиваться под содержимое `SizeToContent` по-моему только при открытии, во всех остальных случаях, нужно пересчитывать размеры самостоятельно. Но могу ошибаться. Чтобы разобраться подробнее, надо видеть как минимум вашу разметку.

Comment: SizeToContent и при открытии не работает, дело в том, что значение Visibility устанавливается в состояние Collapsed через вью модель у меня там всё на MVVM, так вот когда окно только создалось то соответственно окно всё ровно имеет вытянутый вид а элементов нет, может быть вью модель инициализируется после события SizeToContent?